# For Loop Calculation Matlab does not work

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to calculate the residuals (res) for my 19 time series variables. I expect a (nIndices,:) matrix as an outcome from the calculation.
The res calculation works perfectly if applied to 1 individual time series, however it does not work if I try to calculate it with a loop for all time series. It will only calculate res for the first time series (thus I get a 1,: matrix instead of nIndices,:). 
(The nIndices function correctly calculated 19 time series and was applied in the same editor file many times before).

I would appreciate any hints on what I am missing here.

```
for i=1:nIndices  
    res = returns(:,i)-mean(returns(:,i));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to iterate over the *res* variable to store the results. The way it is, it is overwriting the values assigned after each iteration. You should try:

```
for i=1:nIndices
    res(:,i)=returns(:,i)-mean(returns(:,i));
end
```

You could also vectorize your approach by using the *bsxfun*:

```
res = bsxfun(@minus,returns,mean(returns,1));
```

Comment: Works perfectly :-). Thanks for helping out a rookie!